# How to send notification to ajax when database changes in C#? Which one is the best way?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, real-time

i read a little about WebSockets, Comet, WebApi, WCF, etc and want to know the best way to create a server application wich can be read from angular js app, ios app, android app, etc.

Thanks

I want to do something like facebook. The user open the page and let it stopped. After a few seconds (when database updates) the client side upateds by itself. Want to use a server side with C# and client side with angular js. Its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), is a library for Asp.Net to add "real-time web" functionality making use of Html5 Websockets if they are available or fall back to another Comet technique. Right out of the box SignalR provides a javascript library with a client that you can use inside an angularjs controller.

In the server side, you can implement Domain Events whenever something change in your domain then is persisted in the database and let the clients know about that change using SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a real-time framework such as Realtime.co (I work for them). It has APIs for .Net, JavaScript which is what you need for your particular case. You can get a free account at www.realtime.co.

If there's anything you may need help with, please let me know as I am the Developer Evangelist for the company :)

Answer (score 0):

Well to my knowledge Facebook uses a comet approach.  Essentially you set the timeout on a restful page and while its queries return nothing it just sleeps and requeries every so often and only returns a response once changes occur and it gets sent back to your javascript via json or what ever format you have chosen. As soon as the response is return you start another request to the restful page. I beleive there are some comet jquery plugins and projects such as [Bayeux](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/documentation/bayeux)